# how to install my windows phone 7 app in device

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have built my first application for windows phone 7 in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Now i need to launch my application and also want to install it in device. Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can install it from the Application Deployment Tools

Go through this step

> > **Go to Start -> All programs -> Windows Phone Developer Tools -> Application Deployment. This tool allows you to choose a XAP file and deploy it on your developer unlocked phone.**

Answer (score 0):

First, your device should be unlocked and connect to your PC, then Run your solution in VS to your device. or find XapDeploy.exe in this similar path:***'Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\XAP Deployment'***, and deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Unlock your device by running '**Windows Phone Developer Registration**'. You can find it in **Start -> Windows Phone SDK 7.1**.
2. For 32-bit development system go to:
   **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x86**

   For 64-bit development system go to:
   **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Tools\WPConnect\x64**

   and run **WPConnect.exe** it after you have connected the device to your desktop/laptop.
3. Build and deploy after selecting **Windows Phone Device** from **deployment target** and test your app.